# Registering and event handler on a child control and catching the events on a parent

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some work around solutions provided (by Stack Exchange Guru's) for this but am curious on how to achieve this correctly as I've read that an option is to create an event in the child control and subscribe/listen to it in the parent.

I have a child control where onPropertyChanged fires successfully:

```
public class KeypadEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public KeypadEventArgs(double result)
        {
            Result = result;
        }

        public double Result { get; set; }
    }

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Result":                    
                    KeyUpdated(this, new KeypadEventArgs(Result));
                break;
        }
    }
```

It's added to the host control in XAML as follows:

```
<UserControl:KeypadView Width="200" Height="300" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

Now I want the host/parent control to subscribe the child control's KeyUpdated event:

Something like:

```
this.keypadViewModel.KeyUpdated += this.OnKeyUpdated;
...
private void OnKeyUpdated(object sender, KeypadViewModel.KeypadEventArgs e)
    {
        value = e.Result;
    }
```

I understand (sorta) that the MVVM pattern doesn't really want the ViewModel accessing the View. So if the parent never 'creates' the child control how is it aware of it?

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the pattern here slightly but I think the parent is supposed to have it's own ViewModel which does the listening on the child ViewModel. When the child alters it's ViewModel that notifies the parent's ViewModel and the parent's view is updated accordingly.

But like I said I may be misunderstanding.

**EDIT:**

Basically it should work like this:

Child View -> Child View Model -> Parent View Model -> Parent View

So have the Child View alter the Child View Model. Make sure the Parent View Model is listening to an event that notifies it of the change and have the Parent View listen to the Parent View Model from there.

Comment: The parent does have a viewmodel i.e. the last bit in my post. I don't quite get how the parent listen to the child.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, I understand the process. I don't understand how the parent viewmodel can listen to an event on the child. It never created it, it simply hosts it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my sad sorrowful sack. You can command bind up the chain.

It doesn't 100% answer my question but has taught me.

```
Command={Binding Parent.DataContext.SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}
```